# How to insert class in each list of categories?

Tags: functions, theme-development, css

```
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li class="list-inline-item">Category 1</li>
  <li class="list-inline-item">Category 2</li>
  <li class="list-inline-item">Category 3</li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to get a similar output with **wp_list_categories()** function
currently i am trying the code below

```
<ul class="list-inline">  
<?php wp_list_categories( array(
    'title_li' => '',
    'style' => 'list',
) ); ?>
</ul>
```

The output of this is below

```
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li class="cat-item cat-item-4">
    <a href="#">Category 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="cat-item cat-item-4">
    <a href="#">Category 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="cat-item cat-item-4">
    <a href="#">Category 1</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Please help me to achieve the class inside li element.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use ***get_categories*** instead. Here is an example:

```
$categories = get_categories();
$output = '';
if($categories) {
    $output = "<ul class="list-inline">";
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $output .= '<li class="list-inline-item"><a href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a></li>';
    }
    $output .= "</ul>";
}
echo $output;
```

Head over [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/) for more available modification options